# Unable to delete the contents of a Directory in my Home Directory using NSDirectoryEnumerator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have been unable to delete the contents of a directory using NSDirectoryEnumerator.

Here is my method:

```
- (BOOL) deleteDirectoryContents:(NSString *)directoryPath
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    BOOL isDir;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)
    {
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];
        NSLog(@"dirEnum in deleteDirectoryContents is %@", dirEnum);
        NSString *documentsName;
        // NSLog(@"[dirEnum nextObject] is: %@", [dirEnum nextObject]);
        while (documentsName = [dirEnum nextObject])
        {
            NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:documentsName];
            NSLog(@"filePath is: %@", filePath);
            BOOL isFileDeleted = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
            if(isFileDeleted == NO)
            {
                NSLog(@"All Contents not removed");
                success = FALSE;
                break;
            }
            success = TRUE;
        }
        if (success) NSLog(@"All Contents Removed");
    }
    return success;
}
```

And this is my code in my main program:

```
NSString *testDir = @"/Users/grinch/MyTestTemp";
//testDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"MyTestTemp"];
NSLog(@"testDir is: %@", testDir);
BOOL result = [self deleteDirectoryContents:testDir];
NSLog(@"result is: %d", result);
```

Here is my console output:

```
testDir is: /Users/grinch/MyTestTemp
dirEnum in deleteDirectoryContents is <NSAllDescendantPathsEnumerator: 0x60000008c300>
result is: 0
```

I also checked the value of `[dirEnum nextObject]` (by uncommenting the NSLog statement in my code). It returns null.  And I never see the "filePath is" NSLog statement.  So the inner while loop is NEVER executed.

And yes the directory (with files) does exist in my home directory.  I created these files.  I have permissions.  I can easily delete the files in this directory using Finder

What am I missing?

P.S.  I did some more testing.  It looks like my simple program in Xcode does not have permissions to access files and folders in my home directory.  Why?  I have no idea.

Here is my additional test code:

```
NSError *errorMsg;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/Users/grinch/myTestTemp/Hello.txt" error:&errorMsg];
if (errorMsg) NSLog(@"ERROR - File delete errorMsg is: %@", errorMsg);
    
success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:testDir error:&errorMsg];
if (errorMsg) NSLog(@"ERROR - Folder delete errorMsg is: %@", errorMsg);}
```

And here is my console output:

```
2022-09-10 09:56:48.958352-0400 NSAlert[97106:7511815] ERROR - File delete errorMsg is: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“Hello.txt” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/grinch/myTestTemp/Hello.txt, NSUserStringVariant=(
), NSUnderlyingError=0x6040006421f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
2022-09-10 09:56:48.960560-0400 NSAlert[97106:7511815] ERROR - Folder delete errorMsg is: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“MyTestTemp” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/grinch/MyTestTemp, NSUserStringVariant=(
), NSUnderlyingError=0x60400045ff80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why didn't the directory enumerator work?
2. Why doesn't Xcode have the permissions to delete items in my home folder?
3. How can I give Xcode the the ability (or permissions) to delete items in my home directory?

Comment: Re 2 and 3, it’s because your app is “sandboxes”. Searching for that should lead to some useful info.

Comment: @jnpdx - I thought it might be due to some sort of sanboxing issue.  But I still cannot delete the contents of a directory using the method above when my Xcode program not only creates the directory but also creates the files inside the directory.   Here is the strange thing!  My Xcode program  can delete the folder altogether.  I just cannot delete the contents of the directory that the Xcode program creates.  One workaround - Have my program delete the folder and then recreate it.  But why can't I just delete the contents of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bug in my `deleteDirectoryContents:` method above. And as a result, have answered most of my questions!

First, the statement `NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:documentsName];` in the while loop will not work.  One must insert a `/` before `documentsname`.  So the line should be `NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",documentsName];` OR even better use `NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentsName];`.

Now the method `deleteDirectoryContents:` will work as expected.

Here is the code to the fixed method:

```
- (BOOL) deleteDirectoryContents:(NSString *)directoryPath
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    BOOL isDir;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)
    {
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];
        NSLog(@"dirEnum in deleteDirectoryContents is %@", dirEnum);
        NSString *documentsName;
        // NSLog(@"[dirEnum nextObject] is: %@", [dirEnum nextObject]);
        while (documentsName = [dirEnum nextObject])
        {
            //NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",documentsName];
            NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentsName];
            NSLog(@"filePath is: %@", filePath);
            NSError *errorMsg = nil;
            BOOL isFileDeleted = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&errorMsg];
            if (errorMsg) NSLog(@"ERROR - Failed to delete file or folder at: %@.  Error message is: %@", filePath, errorMsg);
            if(isFileDeleted == NO)
            {
                NSLog(@"All Contents not removed");
                success = FALSE;
                break;
            }
            success = TRUE;
        }
        if (success) NSLog(@"All Contents Removed");
    }
    return success;
}
```

And I can confirm that if your program creates the directory and the files within it, the program can also delete these files using `deleteDirectoryContents:` while running in the Xcode sandbox DEPENDING on where the folder was originally created.

If the program creates the folder and files in a temporary directory (e.g. caches directory) NOT the users home folder, it works.

But due to Xcode sandboxing,
`deleteDirectoryContents:` does not appear to work on folder and files created by the program in the users Home directory when running within Xcode.

P.S.  I used the following to obtain a temporary directory name:

```
- (NSString *) get_temporary_dir
{
    NSString *path = nil;
    NSString *bundleName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ([paths count]) {
        path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundleName];
    } else {
        path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundleName];
    }
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[path UTF8String]] autorelease];
}
```

Then the program created the temporary directory using that name.  The program created some files in that temporary directory and then was able to delete them using the `deleteDirectoryContents:` method above.